# Full VB.NET code using C# lib - Twilio example for SMS and MMS message

Tags: c#, vb.net, sms, twilio, mms

I looked everywhere for a VB.NET example for Twilio SMS and MMS messages, after coming up empty I put one together myself. Here is the complete code.  It uses a config file to store SID, Token and Caller. It is setup to take 4 parameters at run time.  It is a Console app created in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: If you want to self-answer, you must post a legitimate, quality question.  Otherwise, it is too bloggy.  (Not my DV)

Comment: What are you taking about?   This is the policy.....Can I answer my own question? Don't worry though I won't be back....

Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site

Answer (score 3):

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System
Imports RestSharp
Imports Twilio

Module Module1
    ' Twilio REST API version

    Const API_VERSION As String = "2010-04-01"

    Sub Main(ByVal CmdArgs() As String)
        Dim account As Twilio.TwilioRestClient
        Dim TwiGetInfo As Twilio.TwilioRestClient
        'Dim recList As Twilio.MessageListRequest
        Dim message As Twilio.Message
        Dim to1 As String
        Dim strBody As String
        Dim SID As String
        Dim Token As String
        Dim Caller As String
        Dim PostBackURL As String
        Dim strFriendlyName As String
        Dim strEventID As String
        Dim SendID As String


        If CmdArgs.Length < 1 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Both a phone number and message variable are needed")
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit")
            Console.ReadKey()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        strFriendlyName = CmdArgs(0)
        to1 = CmdArgs(1)
        strEventID = CmdArgs(2)
        strBody = CmdArgs(3)


        SID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Key0")
        Token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Key1")
        Caller = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Key2")

        PostBackURL = "http://173.111.111.110:8001/XMLResponse.aspx"

        ' Create Twilio REST account object using Twilio account ID and token
        account = New Twilio.TwilioRestClient(SID, Token)
        message = New Twilio.Message


        Dim ArrMedia(0) As String
        ArrMedia(0) = Nothing

        Try
            'Overload 1
            Console.WriteLine(account.SendSmsMessage(Caller, to1, strBody, PostBackURL))
            'Overload 1 - Sends with an Image
            'Console.WriteLine(account.SendMessage(Caller, to1, strBody, ArrMedia, PostBackURL))

        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: {0}", e.Message)
        End Try
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks David.  I am just learning so the only thing that I am not sure of is how to add things within Visual Studio to a config file.

Comment: Glad It was able to help you. After working for a while on that code and posting it here I was left with a very bad taste in my mouth being down voted for sharing I even though that IS the sites policy...

Answer (score 0):

looks like you were spanked for not instantiating your object prior to use?
Post = New Post(Question)
Post.Answer = MyAnswer.text
Thus the error message for accessing a nul object.  :-)